# AngularJS POST request with JSON array data to Express server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I have a static AngularJS website and an Express server running on different domains. The site sends GET requests to the server with a file name as the parameter. The server then requests the file from an S3 bucket, that sends it with "binary/octet-stream" as the "Content-Type". It decrypts the data and sends it back to the site with the same "Content-Type", which then downloads the file. This all works well for single file requests, however I would like to be able to send the server an array of file names all at once, and then be able to download multiple files. I tried sending the file names as a JSON array but I get the error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/decrypt. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.

In my server console, the request shows up as OPTIONS instead of POST. I've also made sure to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in my response headers. How should I go about resolving this?

**UPDATE:**
I was able to resolve the CORS error by adding the following middleware on my router:

```
function allowCrossDomain(req, res, next) {
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    res.status(200).end();
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
}
```

However, I'm still not sure how to send multiple (for each file) "binary/octet-stream" in the response, and download them as files on the static site. Currently I am using [angular-file-saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver) to save files from single requests.

Comment: Are you using [`body-parser`](https://npmjs.com/package/body-parser) as middleware on your Express server? This won't affect the CORS issue you're having but then you will run into the `req.body` being empty since your requests won't know how to parse `Content-Type=application/json`

Comment: Yes. Here is a snippet of my server's javascript file:  `app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a couple things in your server. First off are you using `multer` with `bodyParser`? `Multer` will allow you to add in post calls and will handle passing the data for you.

First AngularJS Post:

```
$http.post(baseUrl + "mypostmethod", o) //o is your object
       .then(function successCallback(resp) {
           console.log(resp)
       }, function errorCallback(resp) {
           console.log(resp)
       });
```

Now as for your `nodejs express` setup, you want to ensure you are using all the proper modules. I will provide the basic list that I use in most of my projects. Also if you use `req.headers.origin` instead of * you sould no longer get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

NodeJS:

```
var express = require('express'),
fs = require('fs'),
spdy = require('spdy'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
multer = require('multer'),
helmet = require('helmet'),
upload = multer(), // this will allow you to pass your object into your post call with express
path = require('path'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
request = require('request'),
app = express(),
http = require('http'),
formidable = require('formidable'); //Good for handling file uploads

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version');
    next();
});
```

These are the basic ones I use in almost all my programs. The most important with `express`is `bodyParser` and `multer` since these will allow you to use your gets and post properly.

Here is an example of a post NodeJS:

```
app.post('/mypostmethod', upload.array(), function(req, res) {
    var body = req.body,
        sess = req.session;
    res.send({
        Status: "Success"
    });
});
```

In this post when you use `upload.array()` that is utilizing `multer` and now `req.body` is the object you passed in with your angular post call.

Let me know if you have any question, I hope this helps.

Comment: [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) is used for file uploads. However, when my server calls the S3 bucket, the file is returned as a "binary/octet-stream". It then processes and decrypts the data, and sends it, using the same "Content-Type", to my static site. In all honesty, I am new to all this and am not sure if I am doing things correctly, and whether there is a better solution to this problem